# QML ComboBox not saving selection

Tags: qt, qml

I have an issue similar to this post: https://forum.qt.io/topic/88519/editable-combobox-not-saving-edited-text/2
Where after I make a selection in the dropdown, if I scroll out of view and then back into view, the selection reverts back to the previous selection. I have these combo boxes in a scrollable TableView which apparently reloads elements every time they come back into view. Also, my ComboBox is not editable but I just want to be able to save the new selection I make.
I know I need to handle onAccepted, but I am not sure how to save the new value I select into the current selection that gets displayed if I leave the view then come back to it. I have 2 methods like this:

```
onDisplayTextChanged: {
  console.log("currentText in onDisplayTextChanged: " + currentText)
  onAccepted()
}                   
onAccepted: {
   console.log("currentText in onAccepted: " + currentText)
}
```

I use onDisplayTextChanged to receive the new value selected that I can pass to a Python 3 script in the future, before calling onAccepted because onAccepted does not trigger for some reason after I click on a new selection. This is definitely not preferable for me though.

Comment: It may/may not solve it, but normally I would define the id of the combobox as well - so `console.log("currentText in onDisplayTextChanged: " + myComboBoxID.currentText)` I user several comboboxes and that' s how i always obtain the data when calling signals let me know if this works and i'll post as answer!

Comment: @Ldweller Not exactly, since I am able to obtain the right `currentText` when I make a selection, and I can see that appear in the main field of the ComboBox. It's just since I am in a `TableView`, when the rows come into view again the ComboBox is refreshed and I lose the previous selection made.

Comment: Ah gotcha, Apologies for not reading properly. If the combobox is being 'destroyed' off screen so the selection is disappearing you could assign the current index to property int when the text is changed?

Comment: @Ldweller I tried to do that, only to realize that it wouldn't work because my ComboBox is dynamically generated with a Loader, the property int would reset itself when the ComboBox gets loaded in again. Thank you for the suggestions; I guess if there is no simple workaround, I will just have to deal with this inconvenience.